# All function only checking one element

Tags: python, list

```
counter = 0
numList = []
beginning = 1
primeOrNot = False
number = int(input("Type a number to check if it's prime."))
while True:
  if number == 2:
    primeOrNot = True
  elif "2" in str(number) or "4" in str(number) or "6" in str(number) or "8" in str(number) or "0" in str(number) or number == 1:
    primeOrNot = False

  numList = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(str(number))]
  for p in range(0, len(numList)): 
    numList[p] = int(numList[p])
  for u in range(2, number):
    if all(o % u == 0 for o in numList):
      counter = counter + 1
  if counter == 0:
    print(numList)
  break
```

I'm trying to make it so it prints a prime if all permutations of the number are also primes.
I've tried to do that with all but what it's doing is checking if atleast 1 of the elements in the list fits the `o % u = 0`. I want it to check if all of the elements work, not if one. Anything I can do using all or using something else?

Example of output now:

Input: `12`

Output: Nothing, Neither 12 nor 21 are prime

Input: `35`

Output: `35, 53`

Even though 35 isn't prime it prints because 53 is.

Comment: You may need to wrap your all statement in brackets all([x for x in l])

Comment: If you're checking that at least one of the elements of `numList` satisfies `o % u == 0`, you should use `any` instead of `all`.

Comment: Just check if `number % 2 == 0`; don't convert it to a string and look (incorrectly) for an even digit. (You would want `str(number).endswith(2)`, etc.)

Comment: This approach is not going to work. As Chepner suggested you should use the modulo operator %.  Use of modulo is critical for finding what numbers divide evenly into the number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation to see what the operation means if you have not heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is faulty:

```
for u in range(2, number):
    if all(o % u == 0 for o in numList):
        counter = counter + 1
```

For each potential divisor in the range, you check to see whether that divisor goes into *every* permutation of the input.  What value of `u` do you envision is going to divide both 35 and 53?

For starters, you need this to be `any`, not `all`.
Second, I strongly recommend that you look up how to find primes and/or factor numbers.  You can learn better ways to handle this, especially when your input string is longer.

Also, note that a `0` or `5` in the input will also ensure that some of the permutations will be composite; assuming that the input is at least two digits, it must be entirely composed of `1379` digits.

```
if number in [2, 3, 5, 7]:
    print("number is prime")
    exit(0)
if any (d not in "1379" for d in str(number)):
    print("This input has composite permutations")
```